# "Running total returns false value"

Tags: java, loops

So, this code is supposed to add each days total and show total sales

But for some reason the answer is always the square of number of days

I thought this was due to other Java files open, so I deleted them, but it didn't help

```
package com.test;

import javax.swing.*;

public class test_3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int days;                       //number of days
        double sales;                  // sales per day
        double TotalSales = 0.0;       // Total sales

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("For how many days is the sales ?");

        days = Integer.parseInt(input);         //converting days into number

        for(int count = 1; count <= days; count++)
        {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter sales amount of day " + count);
            sales = Double.parseDouble(input);

            TotalSales += sales;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total sales is "+ TotalSales);


    }
}
```

What should i do ?

Comment: Your `input` doesn't change so your `sales = Double.parseDouble(input);` always returns same value. You probably wanted to store in each iteration result of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` in `input` like `input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter sales amount of day " + count);
```

should be:

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter sales amount of day " + count);
```

Otherwise `input` is still the value you got from the first prompt (how many days), so you are adding that amount to the total that number of times, hence the squaring.